# adb push: sync but not copy

Tags: adb, file-transfer, rsync

`adb push` seems to push everything into the dest folder regardless of their changed/unchanged states. So it wastes a lot of time. Is it possible to sync rather than copy (i.e. to `rsync` rather than `cp`)?

I see `adb` has a `sync` option, but I'm not quite sure whether it's relevant or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use `adb push --sync`, for example:

```
adb push --sync /home/abc/ /sdcard/abc
```

from `adb --help`:

> ```
> file transfer:
>  push [--sync] LOCAL... REMOTE
>      copy local files/directories to device
>      --sync: only push files that are newer on the host than the device
> ```

but it seems that this function is available for relative newer ADB version such as version **1.0.40**.

Answer (score 4):

While this *answer* is not exactly an explanation on the usage of `adb sync`, it may help when your primary goal is to sync files using `adb`.

You may be interested in [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) which is a Python script that uses `adb` to synchronize files from your computer to your Android device or vice versa.

Example (*computer -> device*):

```
adb-sync /home/abc/ /sdcard/abc
```

Example (*computer <- device*):

```
adb-sync --reverse /sdcard/abc /home/abc/
```

If missing files on the source should be deleted on the target you have to specify `--delete`.

Comment: this python script works for linux only. for windows one can install bash and try [winadb-sync](https://gitlab.com/aIecxs/winadb-sync)

Answer (score 2):

"adb sync" is not relevant in your case. It is used to sync system partition to your connected adb device. It will only work if your phone is rooted and you first need to put system partition into writeable mode. By default it is in read-only mode. Please follow this article for more details:
https://medium.com/@yigitpirildak/syncing-aosp-build-changes-using-adb-sync-885ce12e5cc7

Answer (score 0):

I have made a python script that works like charm for windows.
It copies all the files from the current folder to the device(path can be edited in the code) except the files already present there.
Optionally, -l switch can be used to list the files with copy size before actual copy.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
files=os.listdir('.')
files=set(files)
devPath="/path/on/adb/device"
cmd="adb shell ls -a " + devPath 
deviceFiles=subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True).decode().split('\r\r\n')
deviceFiles=set(deviceFiles)
filesToCopy=files-deviceFiles
size=0
count=0
justList=False
if (len(sys.argv)>1 and sys.argv[1]=='-l'):
    justList=True
for f in filesToCopy:
    count+=1
    size+=os.path.getsize(f)
    if(not justList):
        cmd="adb push "+str(f)+" "+devPath+str(f)
        os.system(cmd)
    print(str(count) + ' ' + str(f))
if(not justList):
    os.system("adb shell rm "+str(devPath)+"/"+sys.argv[0])
print(str(size/1000000) + " Mb")
```

Answer (score -2):

When running `adb` without any commands, you get a list of possible commands, and here it is:

```
adb sync [ <directory> ]     - copy host->device only if changed
                             (see 'adb help all')
```

Looks pretty relevant to me :)

Comment: Would you please give an example on how to use this? Say if I want to sync /home/abc/ on PC to /sdcard/abc/ on device.

Comment: Did you try `adb help all`?

Comment: Yes. It can sync system/data partition. But I just want to sync one folder on sdcard. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It is not implemented in version <= 1.0.31.

Comment: While this command looks promising at first, I couldn't get it to work after a quick try. A real example as requested by [cyker](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29645/adb-push-sync-but-not-copy#comment38613_29647) would be helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question in full, nor it works as the OP wants.

Comment: How did that answer get upvoted? It's not relevant at all.